# Why does Java use Heap Data Structure to Store Object?

Tags: java, memory-management, data-structures, heap, heap-memory

Or it does NOT use Heap "Data-Structure". The name given to the Memory for allocation(Pool of Memory) is just known as "Heap"?

If yes, then is that any relation between Heap Data-Structure and Heap as in Pool of Memory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no relation between [heap memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_memory_allocation#Dynamic_memory_allocation) and [heap the data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29). They just happen to share the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the difference between heap memory and stack memory?

I would explain it, but this answer is pretty sweet

[What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)